# Example of quasicoherent, non-coherent subsheaf of structure sheaf over noetherian scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am having problem with understanding a version of Serra’s affineness criteria: namely, it states that for Noetherian scheme X, the following are equivalent:

- cohomology of quasicoherent subsheaf $D \leq O_X$ vanishes for degree > 0.
- X is affine.

I thought about quasicoherent subsheaf of structure sheaf, and it seems like the sheaf should be coherent. But the statement implies that there are quasicoherent yet not coherent ones - does something happen in the infinite dimension case?

Comment: I think the point here is that there are sheaves of ${\cal O}_X$-submodules of the structure sheaf, which are not quasi-coherent (and in particular not coherent). On a noetherian scheme, as you write, a quasi-coherent subsheaf of a coherent sheaf is coherent.